# How to find the original value based on modulus/reminder and some other information

Tags: code-golf, math, number, arithmetic

This might be a very basic question in terms of math,

```
x % constant = x_modulus

(x + some_number) % constant = y_modulus
```

Given the value of `x_modulus`, `y_modulus`, `(x + some_number)` and `constant`(common in both), output the value of x itself based on these values.

Comment: Are you asking this question because you don't know, or because you want us to write programs that will input these numbers and output x?

Comment: I am asking becase I really don't know in terms of math, how to correlate all these values together. I don't want the complete program, just rough steps would be enough.

Comment: Then maybe you should post this on the [math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/), where you will be very likely to get an answer. On code golf, you would get answers of short programs that could solve your problem but not always direct answers. See why [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204317/maximize-the-function) question was closed.

Comment: Just as a side note, the value of `some_number` is the absolute difference between `x_modulus` and `y_modulus`, which is in turn `x`'s distance with the closest multiple of `constant` larger than x. Therefore it's impossible to find what exactly is the value of x. That greatly simplifies the question.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

Finds the smallest possible value of all values of `x`, takes input as `some_number, constant, x_modulus, y_modulus`

```
α
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3Mb//425TLmMuQwB)

### Explanation

Here are my observations:

- The value of `some_number` is the absolute difference between `x_modulus` and `y_modulus`
- The above value is in turn x's distance with the closest multiple of constant larger than x.

Therefore it's impossible to find what exactly is the value of x. That greatly trivializes the question into a simple absolute difference between `some_number` and `constant`.

The code itself is just absolute difference, I don't feel like explaining it. :D

Comment: What does this do? :)

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate This solves the question. :)